# How to translate 'Computer Support Person'?

Tags: translation

The following seem either incorrect or unprofessional:

```
电脑支持人
电脑服务员
IT男
```

What is a common term **used in business** for 'Computer Support Person'?

Comment: feeding "computer support" to jukuu:  77 examples among which:4.  Computer Support Assistant
 计算机支助助理 7.  Computer Support Coordinator
 计算机支助协调员

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The following seem either incorrect or unprofessional:
>
> 电脑支持人
>
> 电脑服务员
>
> IT男

You are right. It is like calling the person who provides computer related technical support 'computer guy' in English

The more professional term for a person who provides computer related technical support should be '[Computer Support Specialist](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=14&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjA_N2bs7nSAhXm1IMKHbyZCGIQFghWMA0&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.thebalance.com%2Fcomputer-support-specialist-526075&usg=AFQjCNEdc70XJjCAuixsgjsz_l5tfFqR3g&sig2=XPW3PDq7rDPUIeZJ-ccWiw)'

电脑支援专家 or 电脑技术支援专家 (Computer Technical Support Specialist)

*电脑技术支援专家 may be too long a title. We can shorten it to just '电脑技术支援' as the job title. It is perfectly normal in the business world to shorten overly long titles for efficiency. (*NASA personnel would call the Flight Director just 'Flight' during launch.*)

*支援(support/assist) is better choice than 支持(support/ endorse)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the person who provides assistance for others on computer-related things? I think it could simply be called **技术支持人员**. But the problem with this translation is that 技术支持 is a little general rather than focusing on computer. In some companies people may say **IT 人员**.

Answer (score -1):

电脑技术人员 or 计算机技术人员
ps I don't think 支援 is a good idea as it means more "help", often for emergency.